# 'unchecked_mismatch' : is not a member of 'stdext

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have been using Visual Studio 2005 for my project for a long time. The following call has never failed.

stdext::unchecked_mismatch

However once I upgrade it to Visual Studio 2012 the same call results in the error

error C2039: 'unchecked_mismatch' : is not a member of 'stdext'
error C3861: 'unchecked_mismatch': identifier not found

I wonder if it has been moved to other library or it's no longer supported.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the call to a similar method 'mismatch' can be found in

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Then 'mismatch' would be called through std::mismatch

Will further check whether it's fully compatible.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if it has been moved to other library or it's no longer supported.

Well, [`unchecked_mismatch` is not part](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=unchecked_mismatch&emptyWatermark=true&searchButtonTooltip=Search%20MSDN&ac=2#refinementChanges=117&pageNumber=1&showMore=false) of the visual studio `stdext` library anymore. So, it's no longer supported.

Comment: @DeadMG I think Jeffrey answered the question exactly. The OP says I wonder if  it's been moved to another library or .... So the OP clearly doesn't know if it has or not.

Answer (score 0):

You must check with '_MSC_VER >= 1600' and use 'stdext::make_unchecked_array_iterator' like this:

```
#if defined(_STDEXT_BEGIN) && !(defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER < 1400 || _MSC_VER >= 1600)) && !defined(_STLPORT_VERSION)
    stdext::unchecked_mismatch
#else
    std::mismatch
#endif
#if _MSC_VER >= 1600
    (stdext::make_unchecked_array_iterator(scan)+3, stdext::make_unchecked_array_iterator(scanEnd), stdext::make_unchecked_array_iterator(match)+3).first - stdext::make_unchecked_array_iterator(scan));
#else
    (scan+3, scanEnd, match+3).first - scan);
#endif
```